# Rangy: How can I get the span element that is created using the Highlighter module?

Tags: javascript, rangy

I am using the [highlighter module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/HighlighterModule) available in Rangy, and it work great in creating a highlight for the text that is selected.

In terms of changes to the html, the selected text is replaced by a span tag like the following for example:

```
the selected text is <span class="highlight">replaced by a span tag</span> like the
```

What I want to do is get a reference to the span element once it has been created so I can do some other stuff with it. How can this be done?

Please note there may be other spans with or without the highlight tag elsewhere, so these cannot be used to find it.

The important part of the code I have to create the highlight for the selected text is:

```
var highlighter = null;
var cssApplier = null;

rangy.init();
cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("highlight", { normalize: true });
highlighter = rangy.createHighlighter(document, "TextRange");
highlighter.addClassApplier(cssApplier);

var selection = rangy.getSelection();
highlighter.highlightSelection("highlight", selection);
```

Comment: As you mentioned your selected text replaced by span tag worked fine,by any chance you have an example which shows how selected text is replaced by span tag? I have to do the same thing but in my case, it's onclick event and not selected text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was waiting for @TimDown to update his answer with working code. But as he hasn't done that then I will post some myself (which is based on his answer).

The following function will return an array of highlight elements that have been creating, assuming the selection is still valid:

```
function GetAllCreatedElements(selection) {
    var nodes = selection.getRangeAt(0).getNodes(false, function (el) {
        return el.parentNode && el.parentNode.className == "highlight";
    });

    var spans = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        spans.push(nodes[i].parentNode);
    }
    return spans;
}
```

Comment: It's on my list to add something to the highlighter module. I'll post back here again when I have.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that only one `<span>` element will be created: if the selection crosses element boundaries, several spans could be created.

Anyway, since the selection is preserved, you could use the `getNodes()` method of the selection range to get the spans:

```
var spans = selection.getRangeAt(0).getNodes([1], function(el) {
    return el.tagName == "SPAN" && el.className == "highlight";
});
```

Comment: This is returning me a zero length object. I updated with more code samples just in case there is a side effect from elsewhere

Comment: If I just call `getNodes()` it returns one item witch has a `nodeType` of `3`, so it obviously fails to find the span tag. Just to be clear, I am running you code sample immediately after my final sample line of `highlighter.highlightSelection...`

Comment: @musefan: Ah, good point. In that case you could just get that text node's `parentNode`, but it's not ideal. I'll have a think about how to implement something convenient in the highlighter module itself.

Comment: that seems to work. I changed the filter to check the class name of the parentNode and then converted the return node array into an array of parent nodes. Works great on both simple selections and multi-element spanning selections. Keep up the good work!